# Glue for printed vinyl banner

Tags: adhesives

Hey guys I purchased a large printed vinyl banner (3050mm x 766mm). Due to cost reasons, I want to glue this banner to an aluminum sign and it looks like it is coated, maybe plastic or laminate. I’m located in Australia. Which glue should I use to adhere this banner to the sign? It is outdoor and I don’t want glue to damage the print either.

Comment: If the printing is on the front of the vinyl and you want to glue the back, I wouldn't worry about the print being affected by any type of adhesive.  How long does it need to last?  Will it be in a lot of sun?  The vinyl, itself, will deteriorate pretty quickly in a lot of sunlight.  Rain could affect the adhesive at the edges, and heat (even in cold weather, sunlight can really heat a surface), will soften many adhesives and deteriorate them over time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which adhesives work well when gluing vinyl to plastic?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/3621/which-adhesives-work-well-when-gluing-vinyl-to-plastic)

Comment: @Elmy, there's an answer there that might work, but not necessarily the best solution for this application.  Applying a smooth layer of silicone caulk can be difficult, and generally, holding up to the elements and sunlight heating outside is different from a decoration inside.  While an answer there might coincidentally work, it seems better to elicit recommendations tailored to the specific requirements.  The requirements are different enough that I'd vote to keep these separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

Neither material is absorbent and both will prevent solvent from evaporating, so a contact cement would be good for this. I don't know what's available in Australia, but 3M makes [HI-Strength 90 Spray Adhesive](https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/p/d/b40069424/) that sticks to both kinds of materials and should hold up outside in the sun and rain. The link says it's for industrial use but a different color can of the same name is sold in the big hardware chains. Disclaimer: I haven't actually tried it myself (but it's used industrially and commercially).